# react.js: how to load local react.js instead of using online ones

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

So I'm new to react.js and have been following the tutorial created by facebook. (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html; this one).

Now I finish the tutorial I want to expand a little bit on top of it. However, I notice that in the tutorial, in index.html, it is using online locations for loading react and other modules. One example is like this:

How to change the src from online to local? I've download react through npm. All files are in a folder called react2. index.html is in react2/public, server.js is in react2 root folder; while react is in react2/node_modules/react/react.js. I've tried to change src into "../node_modules/react/react.js" and "/home/.../react2/..." and tried to add file:/// in the front, but nothing worked.

btw, this is my first question on stackoverflow and I'm not really familiar with the rules. If I did something wrong in posting please tell me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you have to put react in a public folder, which server are you using?

Comment: You should be using either `browserify` or `webpack` to bundle all your JS into one file. It will simplify your development and will make your website load faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import react in a html file through the src attribute of the script tag, you should download the files directly from here [react-15.2.0.min.js](https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/t39.3284-6/13591539_1089962347742008_810694221_n.js) and [react-dom-15.2.0.min.js](https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/t39.3284-6/13571104_291874534490665_389514355_n.js) and save them into a lib folder, or wherever you want.

If you download React from npm you have to import react like any other npm package and generate a bundle that you can import in your html file with a bundler like browserify or webpack. You can use the react and react-dom packages. After installing it using npm install --save react react-dom, you can use:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, ...);
```

Comment: Not working for me (

Answer (score 1):

Speaking this way is hard to detect what problem is. I'm almost sure is related to call React in a wrong path.

You can open your Developer Tools inside your preferred browser, to check which source your app is calling React. After opening it, go to the `console` tab and there you can check for every missing file.

Also, make sure you're running React on a server. Which is required for most actions you'll use. If React is being called properly, but isn't working, maybe it could be the problem.